# How can i create boolean column and assign value 1 when creating/altering a column of a mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying something like this =>

```
alter table tablename modify columnname "boolean" default 1 NOT NULL;
```

Which is the correct format to create boolean column ?

Comment: I thought it was just `tinyint`

Comment: are tinyint and boolean same ?

Comment: @guru, almost, boolean = tinyint(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE columnname columnname BOOLEAN DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL
```

Is this what you are after?

Answer (score 3):

```
alter table tablename modify columnname boolean default true NOT NULL;
```

Don't put quotes around `boolean`.

I tested this on a column that was `int` and it worked.

Comment: boolean default true and boolean default 1 , are they same ?

Comment: modify columnname and change columnname , are they similar ?

Comment: `modify` alters just the column datatype. `change` alters the column datatype and also renames the column (not needed here).

Answer (score 0):

instead of boolean use TINYINT(1). This is preferred on InnoDB database engine

Comment: What is prefered in MyISM database engine ?

Comment: Nonsense, boolean is tinyint(1), there is no difference.